# How to create single sound file from multiple chunks of sounds in Android

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording

I am creating a drum app in which I have to do two things

1. Play various sounds
2. If user chooses to record the sound, I have to make the audio file of whatever music user has played

The App works something like this - 
When user hits button A, I play SoundA. If user hits B, I play SoundB and likewise...

So to playback instead of recording the sound, what I am thinking is, when user clicks "start recording" button- 
if I maintain the timestamps of when user has clicked the buttons, I can reproduce the better quality final output just by mixing the sounds I already have.

e.g. user hit Button A at 00:01 second, button B at 00:05 seconds, so on and so forth

What I am not sure about is - how to create an audio file and insert these sounds at specific time period i.e. Sound A at 00:01 second, Sound B at 00:05 second...so on and so forth.

Any help on this would be of great help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Two part answer:

**Solution 1**: One idea that comes to mind is rather than trying to record the resulting audio, you could record the buttons that they press, and recreate the sequence when they play the file.

So your "recording" file would be something like:

- A 0001 (play A at 1 second)
- B 0005
- A 0006 (adding some more of my
  own)
- C 0008
- ...
- B 0194 (using pure seconds instead of minutes/seconds)

So when they want to play the "recording" you set up a timer that will wait the appropriate amount of time, then play the appropriate sound.  So with my example above you would:

- Wait one second and play sound A
- Wait four more seconds and play sound B
- Wait another second and play sound A again
- Wait two seconds and play sound C
- etc.

**Solution 2**: This would be more appropriate if you want to be able to export the recording outside your app, and thus need a real audio file.

This assumes you have your sounds available in a raw format (WAV is usable here, but MP3 or other formats would have to be decoded first).  This also assumes that all the sounds are consistent regarding samples/second, stereo/mono, 8-bit/16-bit samples, etc.  Then when they finish the recording, allocate an array (or two if you do stereo) of the appropriate size.  So if the recording is 11 seconds, and your sounds are 16-bit mono at 44100 samples/second, you allocate an array of 485100 shorts (485100=11*44100).  If that is too large, then you may need to do this in shorter segments (such as a second at a time) and be ready for your sounds to cross between segments.  16-bit values are signed shorts, so you should just be able to initialize your array to 0, and add each sound at the appropriate place.  Note that 8-bit values are unsigned with an offset, so you will have to adjust for the offset when you add the samples.  Then write the file in a format (probably WAV, see http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html for a description of the WAV file format).  If you want the file to be MP3 or some other compressed format, there are almost certainly classes out there to do the compression for you, but I can't help you much in that area.

Edit: Code sample (in C for Windows) that creates a .WAV file:

```
/* Create a .WAV file with a specified set of chirps */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys\stat.h>
#include<ctype.h>

/* length of one bit in 44100Hz units */
#define BIT_LEN 88.5

/* length of one half-cycle */
#define HALF_CYCLE (BIT_LEN/8)

/* samples per second */
#define SAMP_RATE 44100

/* seconds before chirps start */
#define LEAD_SILENCE 5

struct {
    unsigned long ID;           /* FILE ID "RIFF" */
    unsigned long Len;          /* file length (excluding 8-byte header) */
    unsigned long DataType;     /* Data type 'WAVE' (start of main file) */
} FileHeader;

struct {
    unsigned long ID;           /* chunk ID "DATA" */
    unsigned long Len;          /* chunk length */
} DataHeader;

struct {
    unsigned long ID;           /* chunk ID "FMT " */
    unsigned long Len;          /* chunk length */
    short FormatTag;            /* format (1 if uncompressed) */
    unsigned short Channels;        /* # of channels (mono, stereo, etc) */
    unsigned long SampPerSec;       /* # of samples per second */
    unsigned long AvgBytesPerSec;   /* # of bytes played per second */
    unsigned short BlockAlign;      /* Size of a 'frame' in bytes */
    unsigned short BitsPerSamp;     /* bits per sample */
} FormatHeader;

#define ID_RIFF 0x46464952  /* 'RIFF' (FFIR) */
#define ID_WAVE 0x45564157  /* 'WAVE' (EVAW) */
#define ID_DATA 0x61746164  /* 'data' (atad) */
#define ID_FMT  0x20746d66  /* 'fmt ' ( tmf)*/

/* count # of pos/negative parts done */
int pcount=0;
/* how many will fit on a normal line? */
#define PCOUNT_MAX 14

void disp_id( char * lbl, long ID )
{
   union {
      long l;
      char c[6];
   } u;

   u.l = ID;
   u.c[4] = 0;

   printf( lbl, u.c );
}

/* note where the samples begin */
unsigned long SampleStart;  /* where do samples begin? */

/* one-second chirp segment */

short NewChirp[SAMP_RATE],  /* 1-second block with chirp */
    Silence[SAMP_RATE];     /* 1-second silence */

/* insert a byte into the chirp */
/* location is specified in bit time units */
void insert_byte( int location, int value )
{
    int i, j;
    int data;   /* value to write to item */
    int dloc;   /* where we are within the byte */
    int cycle;

    printf("Inserting byte %d", value);

    /* insert bits in little-endian order */
    data = (value<<2) + 2;  /* add "10" to the number */

    /* round cycle low/high times to 11 samples low, 11 samples high */
    /* use BIT_LEN to put it in the proper place */
    for( i=0; i<10; i++ )
        if ( data & (1<<i) )
        {
            printf(" %d: ", i );

            /* have a 1-bit to insert, where should it be? */
            /* insert 4 cycles */
            for( cycle=0; cycle<4; cycle++ )
            {
                /* note: this may leave 0 samples between cycles or bits */
                dloc = (int)(location + i*BIT_LEN + cycle*(BIT_LEN/4) + 0.5);
                printf(" %d", dloc );

                /* insert 11 low samples */
                for( j=0; j<11; j++ )
                {
                    NewChirp[ dloc+j ] = -30000;
                }

                /* insert 11 high samples */
                for( j=11; j<22; j++ )
                {
                    NewChirp[ dloc+j ] =  30000;
                }
            }
        }

    printf("\n");
} /* insert_byte */

/* insert a chirp with the given value */
void insert_chirp( FILE *f, float speed, float incline )
{
   int i, i_speed, i_incline, i_chksum;

   /* convert values to integers */
   i_speed = (int)( speed*10 + 0.5 );
   i_incline = (int)( incline*10 + 0.5 );
   i_chksum = (i_speed + i_incline) & 0x0ff;

   /* set everything to 0 in advance */
   memset( NewChirp, 0, SAMP_RATE );

   /* start inserting chirp parts */
   insert_byte(  0, i_speed );
   insert_byte( (int)(10*BIT_LEN+0.5), i_incline );
   insert_byte( (int)(20*BIT_LEN+0.5), i_chksum );
   insert_byte( (int)(40*BIT_LEN+0.5), i_speed );
   insert_byte( (int)(50*BIT_LEN+0.5), i_incline );
   insert_byte( (int)(60*BIT_LEN+0.5), i_chksum );

   /* write the chirp */
   fwrite( NewChirp, 1, SAMP_RATE, f );
} /* insert_chirp */

/* maximum # of chirps per file we will permit */
#define CHIRP_MAX 50

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *f;                    /* workout information file */
    FILE *audio;                /* output WAV file */

    /* hold information about the chirps */
    struct {
        int second_count;           /* where does this occur in seconds */
        float speed;                /* speed to use */
        float incline;              /* treadmill incline */
    } chirp_list[CHIRP_MAX+1];

    int chirp_count;                /* # of chirps in the current workout */
    int cur_chirp;              /* which chirp are we working on? */
    int cur_time;               /* current time we are writing */

    char wname[100];                /* workout name from the file */
    int len;
    char dbuf[100];             /* one chirp line from the file */

    /* for reading one chirp */
    int sec;
    int seqno;
    float speed, incline;
    int sec_length;             /* length of workout in seconds */

    printf("initializaing\n");
    /* build our 1 second of silence */
    memset( Silence, 0, SAMP_RATE );

    printf("opening input file %s\n", argv[1] );

    /* open the description file */
    fopen_s( &f, argv[1], "r" );

    if ( f == NULL )
    {
        printf("Unable to open file %s\n", argv[1] );
        return 1;
    }

    /* read one workout from the file */
    while( 1==1 )
    {
        printf("reading one line from the workout\n");
        /* at end of file? */
        if ( feof(f) )
        {
            return 0;
        }

        /* get the header line */
        fgets( wname, 90, f );

        /* did we now detect end of file? */
        if ( feof(f) )
        {
            return 0;
        }

        /* read the workout stages */
        chirp_count = 0;
        sec_length = 45;        /* account for lead and trail time */
        while( 1==1) {
            fgets( dbuf, 90, f );
            printf("read line %s", dbuf );

            /* did we now detect end of file? - Shouldn't happen, but check */
            if ( feof(f) || strlen(dbuf)<3 )
            {
                break;
            }

            if ( ! isdigit( dbuf[0] ) )
            {
                /* should have only numbers here */
                return 3;
            }

            /* extract the information */
            sscanf_s( dbuf, "%d %f %f %d", &seqno, &speed, &incline, &sec );
            printf("speed=%3.1f, incline=%3.1f, time=%d\n", speed, incline, sec );

            /* save it for later */
            chirp_list[chirp_count].second_count = sec;
            sec_length += sec;
            chirp_list[chirp_count].speed = speed;
            chirp_list[chirp_count].incline = incline;

            /* move to next chirp */
            chirp_count++;
        }

        /* replace ".txt" with ".wav" for the output filename */
        if ( strlen( argv[1] ) > 90 )
        {
            printf("Error: path/filename too long\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        strcpy( wname, argv[1] );
        strcpy( wname+strlen(wname)-3, "wav" );

        /* start creating our WAV file */       
        printf("Creating output file %s\n", wname );
        fopen_s( &audio, wname, "wb" );

        printf("Overall length: %d seconds\n", sec_length );

        /* create header */
        FileHeader.ID = ID_RIFF;
        FileHeader.DataType = ID_WAVE;

        /* create our format header */
        FormatHeader.ID = ID_FMT;
        FormatHeader.Len = 16;                      /* chunk length */
        FormatHeader.FormatTag = 1;                 /* format (1 if uncompressed) */
        FormatHeader.Channels = 1;                  /* # of channels */
        FormatHeader.SampPerSec = SAMP_RATE;        /* # of samples per second */
        FormatHeader.AvgBytesPerSec = SAMP_RATE*2;  /* # of bytes played per second */
        FormatHeader.BlockAlign = 1;                /* Size of a 'frame' in bytes */
        FormatHeader.BitsPerSamp = 16;              /* bits per sample */

        /* create our data header */
        DataHeader.ID = ID_DATA;
        DataHeader.Len = (sec_length+LEAD_SILENCE) * SAMP_RATE;

        /* update overall length, account for various headers except main RIFF part */
        /*      -- include 'WAVE' part of main header */
        FileHeader.Len = DataHeader.Len + 4 + 
                + sizeof(FormatHeader) + sizeof( DataHeader );

        /* write it to the file */
        fwrite( &FileHeader, sizeof(FileHeader), 1, audio );

        /* write it to the file */
        fwrite( &FormatHeader, sizeof(FormatHeader), 1, audio );

        /* write it to the file */
        fwrite( &DataHeader, sizeof(DataHeader), 1, audio );

        /* start with silence */
        printf("Writing lead-in\n" );
        for( cur_time = 0; cur_time < LEAD_SILENCE; cur_time++ )
        {
            fwrite( &Silence, 1, SAMP_RATE, audio );
        }

        /* now do the chirps */
        for( cur_chirp=0; cur_chirp < chirp_count; cur_chirp++ )
        {
            printf("Chirp #%d, time=%d, speed=%4.1f, incline=%4.1f\n",
                    cur_chirp+1, chirp_list[cur_chirp].second_count,
                    chirp_list[cur_chirp].speed, chirp_list[cur_chirp].incline );

            /* add the chirp */
            insert_chirp( audio, chirp_list[cur_chirp].speed,
                    chirp_list[cur_chirp].incline );

            /* add enough silence between this chirp and the next */
            for( cur_time = 1;
                cur_time < chirp_list[cur_chirp].second_count; cur_time++ )
            {
                /* add another second of silence */
                fwrite( &Silence, 1, SAMP_RATE, audio );
            }
        }

        /* add the stop chirp */
        printf("Stop chirp\n");
        insert_chirp( audio, 25.2, 25.2 );

        /* end with 30 seconds of silence */
        printf("Writing 30 seconds lead-out\n" );
        for( cur_time = 1; cur_time < 30; cur_time++ )
        {
            fwrite( &Silence, 1, SAMP_RATE, audio );
        }

        /* done with this workout */
        fclose( audio );
    } /* while reading workouts */
}
```

Comment: Hi Eugene, Thanks for your answer. I was more or less clear on my logic regarding how to play sound - but wasnt clear on how to pull it off technically in Android - so any reference regards to that would be really helplful. Thanks.

Comment: I think for playing sound your best bet is to use the SoundPool class - Best for playing multiple sounds possibly at the same time, especially if they will be short sounds.  That seems to fit your app best.

Comment: Thanks Eugene for your answering the comment. My recorded sounds are playing good now, but I am playing it locally i.e. I havent created the file and played the sounds. If you look at my questions, I was more keen on learning how to make the single sounds file (mp3, wav) or anything of that sort ?

Comment: Added an example (in C for Windows) of a program that creates a .wav file.  Hopefully it won't be too hard to adapt that to Android/Java.  I don't have any examples of creating .mp3 files directly.